# $Z_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability and $W_n$ a series of random variables, implies $W_nZ_n\rightarrow 0$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Yesterday [you helped me prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585983/given-z-n-rightarrow-0-in-probability-and-w-a-random-variable-proving-wz-n?lq=1) that $Z_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability and $W$ a random variable, implies $WZ_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability.

Does this imply that for every series $W_n$ of random variables we get $W_nZ_n\rightarrow 0$? I'm not sure about it. At first I thought this is true because for every specific $n_0$ we proved $Z_nW_{n_0}\rightarrow 0$. But still it doesn't feel right because it doesn't take into account the behavior of $W_n$ as a series.

What do you think?

Comment: You probably meant to link this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585983/given-z-n-rightarrow-0-in-probability-and-w-a-random-variable-proving-wz-n?lq=1

And to prove the new statement, look at the original proof and replace $W$ with $W_n$,

Comment: Can you have $W_n = 1/Z_n$?

Comment: If $W_n$ converges in probability to _some_ random variable, then the answer is yes. However, more information is needed if the $W_n$ do not converge. (As @GEdgar noted, this does not hold for $W_n=1/Z_n$).

Answer (score 2):

With Slutky's Theorem one could get that
\begin{align*}
W_n Z_n \rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
in distribution, if $W_n \rightarrow W$ in distribution.
Correct me if I am wrong but I do not see why this should hold when $W_n$ is not bounded in any way, i.e. $W_n = O_P\left( c \right)$ for a $c \in \mathbb{R}$.